# unable to play local video in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I'm trying to play locally recorded video on html5  video
but every time i try I'm getting

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)**
here is the url I'm giving to the video tag
**http://localhost:8080/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID20201024134007.mp4**

[image: here is the video data that I'm getting when saving the video.]

here is the code

```
let testUrl = this.videoService.localFileUrl.fullPath;
testUrl = testUrl.replace('file:///', 'http://localhost:8080/');
console.log("filePath=======>", testUrl)
this.filePath = testUrl;
```

Comment: The path seems to be on the device's memory card. Does the app have permissions to read files from that location ?

Comment: Yes I do I have added rear write permissions in android manifest file and also asked for storage permission in didEnter life cycle

Comment: Do you find a solution ? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is being caused by this line of the code :

```
testUrl = testUrl.replace('file:///', 'http://localhost:8080/');
```

localhost is used if the file being accessed is stored on the server. Since this file is being stored on the device, it needs the file path. You can use the path under `fullpath` or `localURL` as specified in the image attached to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import { WebView } from '@ionic-native/ionic-webview/ngx';

constructor(
    ... private _webview: WebView
  ) { }

...
this.resourceLocalPath = this._webview.convertFileSrc(this.resourceLocalPath);
```

where this.resourceLocalPath is the path to your file (starts with file:///)